# ASP.NET MVC - Using Ninject bindings outside of controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3, and Ninject. I've set up the standard code implementation in "AppStart_NinjectMVC3.cs" that sets up the bindings and adds a kernel to the DependencyResolver like this:

```
    public static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>();
        ...
    }

    public static void Start() {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        RegisterServices(kernel);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectServiceLocator(kernel));
    }
```

All is working well in my controllers - dependencies are being resolved fine.

I'd like to be able to use Ninject and these bindings outside of controllers, and outside of the MVC stack. For example, I have a bunch of regular aspx pages  in which I'd like to use my ninject kernel, and some code hanging off global.asax too.

Can I re-use my Ninject kernel in these other places, or do I need to also register a kernel in my Global.asax appstart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current development release found on http://teamcity.codebetter.com provides support for side a side usage of ordinary aspx pages, mvc and wcf. You might want to have a look at this.

Be aware this is a development version and it is not tested very well. Nevertheless, I think it should be pretty much stable. But as it is work in progress it the interface can change. Also I won't give a lot of support before I have written the Ninject 2.4 preview blog about this change.

You need

- Ninject
- Ninject.Web.Common
- Ninject.Web
- Ninject.Web.MVC3

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info, I'll check this out. Does this "just work" with the MVC-defined kernel, and how do I get a handle on it from a web page?

Comment: You don't need to access the kernel. It injects ordinary webpages and controls. But you have to use property injection for them.

Comment: Thats great thanks - I think I'll wait for 2.4 and then grab it from there, I can wait for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [Ninject MVC Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) within my ASP.NET MVC application.

Here is the manner in which I've achieved what I think you're trying to accomplish.

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Overridden Ninject method that is called once the application has started and is initialized
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        // Tell the MVC Framework to use our implementation of metadataprovider.
        ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new XXX.myNamespace.MetadataProvider();

        // Tell the MVC Framework to use our CartModelBinder class
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Cart), new CartModelBinder());
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Establish a reference to our DIFactory object
    /// <remarks>
    /// This application currently uses Ninject for dependency injection.
    /// </remarks>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return DIFactory.GetNinjectFactory();
    }

    // snip... additional global.asax.cs methods
}
```

**DIFactory.cs:**

```
/// <summary>
/// This class is used as a container for dependency injection throughout the entire application
/// </summary>
public class DIFactory
{
    public static IKernel _kernel = null;
    /// <summary>
    /// Method used to create a single instance of Ninject's IKernel
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IKernel</returns>
    public static IKernel GetNinjectFactory()
    {
        if (_kernel == null)
        {
            var modules = new INinjectModule[]
            {
                new ServiceModule()
            };

            _kernel = new StandardKernel(modules);
        }
        return _kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method used as a service locator for the IConfiguration interface
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IConfiguration CreateConfigurationType()
    {
        return _kernel.Get<IConfiguration>();
    }

    // snip....additional public static methods for all other Interafaces necessary
}
```

**ServiceModule.cs:**

```
/// <summary>
/// Configures how abstract service types are mapped to concrete implementations
/// </summary>
internal class ServiceModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IConfiguration>().To<XXX.myNamespace.Configuration>();

        // snip... all other bindings to interfaces
    }
}
```

**Use in other classes besides Controllers:**

**UserInteraction.cs:**

```
public class UserInteraction : IUserInteraction
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;

    public bool SubmitFeedback(Feedback feedback)
    {
        try
        {
            this.configuration = DIFactory.CreateConfigurationType();
            // snip additional logic...

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // snip
        }
    }
 }
```